SERVICE labeling with federated Wikidata Query Service
Wikidata Query Service is split into two separate SPARQL endpoints: query-main and query-scholar (the old query endpoint should be working until some time in 2025). A lot of "old" queries will have to be rewritten to a federated form and among them are some of those queries using the labeling SERVICE. How would we best apply the Wikidata Query Service labeling SERVICE in this connection?
There are complexities: Sometimes we which to delay the labeling as much as possible, e.g., in connection with a GROUPing, and sometimes a variable has items that comes from both the main or the scholarly graph, e.g., ?written_work wdt:P50 [] would be an example.
One or my attempts was https://w.wiki/Bmqs
SELECT 
  ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE {
  BIND(wd:Q27453085 AS ?person)

  { ?item wdt:P0050 ?person . }
  UNION
  { SERVICE <https://query-scholarly.wikidata.org/sparql> { ?item wdt:P0050 ?person . } }
   
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en". } 
  SERVICE <https://query-scholarly.wikidata.org/sparql> {
    BIND(?item AS ?item)
    BIND(?itemLabel AS ?itemLabel)
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en". }
  }
}

This does not work satisfactorily: Some items are not labeled (I see, e.g., wd:Q4045846 not labeled).
I tried another one https://w.wiki/Bmqp
SELECT 
  ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE {
  BIND(wd:Q27453085 AS ?person)

  { ?item wdt:P0050 ?person . }
  UNION
  { SERVICE <https://query-scholarly.wikidata.org/sparql> { ?item wdt:P0050 ?person . } }
   
  {
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en". }
  }
  UNION
  {
    SERVICE <https://query-scholarly.wikidata.org/sparql> {
      BIND(?item AS ?item)
      BIND(?itemLabel AS ?itemLabel)
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en". }
    }
  }
  FILTER (?itemLabel != SUBSTR(STR(?item), 32))
}

And that seems to work as far as I can tell, but it seems not pretty to me.
I am wondering whether more efficient or prettier query for federated SERVICE labeling?
The query is related to problems occurring in Scholia (see https://scholia.toolforge.org/event/Q119153957#people) and Synia (see https://synia.toolforge.org/#scientificevent/Q119153957 "Persons" panel).

BIND(?itemLabel AS ?itemLabel) doesn't work because the label service will be evaluated later during the projection. Also it looks like two label services interfere each other.

Check this query: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel1 ?itemLabel2 WHERE {
BIND(wd:Q27453085 AS ?person)
{ ?item wdt:P0050 ?person. }
UNION
{
SERVICE https://query-scholarly.wikidata.org/sparql {
?item wdt:P0050 ?person.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en" . ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel2 }
}
}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en". ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel1 }
}` - the labels will be retrieved, but only if we bind to different variables than the default one.

with `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
BIND(wd:Q27453085 AS ?person)
{ ?item wdt:P0050 ?person. }
UNION
{
SERVICE https://query-scholarly.wikidata.org/sparql {
?item wdt:P0050 ?person.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en" .  }
}
}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en".  }
}` only the "outer" label service seems to be evaluated and binds the labels.

what you could do: `SELECT ?item (COALESCE(IF(STRSTARTS(STR(?itemLabel1), "Q"), ?itemLabel2, ?itemLabel1)) AS ?itemLabel) WHERE {
BIND(wd:Q27453085 AS ?person)
{ ?item wdt:P0050 ?person. }
UNION
{
SERVICE https://query-scholarly.wikidata.org/sparql {
?item wdt:P0050 ?person.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en" . ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel2 }
}
}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en". ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel1 }
}`

@UninformedUser It is not correct that BIND(?itemLabel AS ?itemLabel) does not work. You can try and uncomment the line a see that the labeling does not work if that particular line is not there.

the label service definitely does not work with a BIND. try this query where I bind it to another variable which avoids that we do the way over the projection part which indeed is the point where the labels are bound then by naming convention:  `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel2 WHERE {
BIND(wd:Q27453085 AS ?person)
?item wdt:P0050 ?person.
BIND(?itemLabel AS ?itemLabel2)
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],mul,en".  }
}`

The label service definitely does work with BIND. You can try the link https://w.wiki/Bmqp I provided in the question.
